# MySQL console error unknown option '--root'

Tags: mysql

When I try to access mysql in the command line get the following error:

> mysql: unknown option '--root'

Mysql is installed via brew, version 5.6.27, OSX El Capitan with SIP turned off.

Comment: `mysql -u root -p password db_name`

Comment: What is the command you are using to access mysql?

Comment: Every command I'm using to access MySQL is giving me this error

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread however, it can help someone. I came up with the same issue then later I have discovered that there was a wrong entry in *.my.cnf* file in my home folder. You probably have a wrong entry on your

> /root/.my.cnf or .my.cnf

file on your home directory.

Renaming the file will help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had such error (*but with message "mysql: unknown option --mysqld]"*) when forgot opening '**[**' symbol in **/etc/mysql/my.cnf**, It was looking like:

```
mysqld]   #<-- forgot opening [
innodb-file-format=barracuda
innodb-file-per-table=1
...
```

Check this! (*thanks to Siru, found in a moment!*)